# how to upload file NOT using multipart encoding? (maybe use octect or something)

Tags: javascript, html, http

We would like our web app to be able to upload files from a browser(user selects file the standard way) BUT either ajax or not ajax and would prefer the file takes up the whole body of the POST with nothing else in the body(ie. we don't really want all the other fields and only need the file contents)

I read something about there may be a way to do this with ajax but can't seem to find any info related to application/octect-stream or something.

Has anyone done this before and what does the html/javascript look like for this to work correct such that this is also a chunked file and not sent to the webserver as one huge giant thing.

Is there something in html 5 that helps here.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only way to do this with HTTP is a multipart document, ajax or no ajax. The other alternative is to use web sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple to do this, simply pass the blob/file as the parameter to your call to the send method on your XHR instance, for example:

```
function uploadFile(blobOrFile) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://mydomain.com/upload", true);
    xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}
```

Note that this will only work in File API browsers, (i.e. not IE9 and older)

Comment: Yes, this is true, but don't you end up with a multipart document just as you would with a straight form post?

Comment: No, you end up with a POST request with a payload that is made up entirely of the file.

Comment: Oh well then I guess that should  do it :)  Do you know if you'd get the same thing from an ordinary form that only has a single file `<input>` in it?

Comment: It depends entirely how you send the request.  If you submit the form, then it will result in a MPE POST.  If you are using a modern browser, and you access the `File` object associated with the file input (`fileInput.files[0]`), pass it into a `FormData` instance (`formData.append("file", file)`), then you will also wind up with a MPE request, assuming you pass the `FormData` instance as a param to the `send` method.  However, if you take the same `File` grabbed from the file input's `files` property, and pass it as an argument to `send`, you now have a POST made up entirely of the file.

Comment: Oh OK now I see what you're saying. Yes that makes perfect sense.

Comment: will the xhr.send(blobOrFile) result in chunking the file?  or will it send a file that is too large happily to the server potentially blowing out the server memory (for a 5Gig file maybe on a 2gig RAM server).  thanks, Dean

Comment: It will send the entire file.  If you want to break the file up into chunks, you will need to make use of the [`slice` method on the file/blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), and send each piece in a separate request.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am going to end up trying the websockets method like this code does(just found this)

https://github.com/jberger/GalileoSend/blob/master/js/galileo_send.js

as we have 4 stateless servers behind a load balancer and if I go the xmlhttprequest method, I end up with chunks on different servers which is ok as long as I copy the header of the file to be put in each chunk, but I just decided to forgo that and do websocket which hopefully also reduces the http overhead a little to though I will miss out on some parallelism that I could have had with xmlhttprequest.

it is just another answer I thought I would add here to be complete on the choices I think we all have.